# How to replace multiple NA rows with adjacent rows by group in dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to replace multiple rows having NA values with adjacent observed rows by group in a dataframe of R.

The data looks like:

```
| id | a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 | 
| ---|----|----|----|----|
| 1  | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  |
| 1  | 2  | 2  | 2  | 2  |
| 1  | NA | NA | NA | NA |
```

what I want to get is:

```
| id | a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 | 
| ---|----|----|----|----|
| 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  |
| 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  |
| 1  | 2  | 2  | 2  | 2  |
| 1  | 2  | 2  | 2  | 2  |
```

by replacing NA rows with adjacent observations (rows above and below) by group.

I tried:

```
sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i){if(is.na(df[i,2:5])){df[i,2:5] <<- df[(i+1),2:5]}})

sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i){if(is.na(df[i,2:5])){df[i,2:5] <<- df[(i-1),2:5]}})
```

but I cannot replace it by group.

Can anyone help this?

Cheers,

Comment: You can use `tidyr::fill(df, a1:a4, .direction = "downup")`. If you mean with 'by group' that you want to group by id, you can use `library(dplyr)` and `df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  tidyr::fill(a1:a4, .direction = "downup") `.

Comment: @Bas Thank you so much! Your neat command perfectly works.